# Chrome datepicker showing "dd/mm/yyyy" by default instead of date from ngModel

Tags: html, angular

I'm currently using date-fns module to get the current date and binding it to the following code below.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <label for="endDateRegistered" class="form-label">End Date Registered</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="endDateRegistered" name="filterBy.endDate" [(ngModel)]="filterBy.endDate">
</div>
```

The issue i'm facing is that in safari, I'm correctly seeing the date in the input field when the page loads. However, in chrome, I am seeing the placeholder "dd/mm/yyyy" instead. Is there any way to remove this so it shows the date?

Below is the code of getting the date and assigning it.

```
  filterBy = {
     stadium: '',
     endDate: format(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy')
  }
```

Comment: what is the implementation of `format(...)` ?

Comment: @grizzasd I am importing date-Fns and using the formatting feature of that module